# how to monitor server using Appdynamics?

Tags: health-monitoring, appdynamics, performance-monitor, server-monitoring

I have an application that is generating 3 kind of log files

- Transaction log
- Server log
- Fatal log

and I want to analyse the performance of my server using appdynamics so what kind of data my logs should be generating to generate analytics for server health, performance, throughput, server utilization?

Comment: do you use ***ASP.NET health monitoring*** ?

Answer (score 1):

That's the beauty of APM is you don't need to deal with logging to get performance data. APM tools instrument the applications themselves regardless of what the code does (logging, generating metrics, etc). AppDynamics can collect log data, and provide similar capabilities to what a log analytics tool can do, but it's of less value than the transaction tracing and instrumentation you get. Your application has to be built in a supported language (Java, .NET, PHP, Python, C++, Node.js) and if it's web or mobile based you can also collect client side performance data and unify between both frontend and backend. If you have questions just reach out and I can answer them for you. Good luck!

Comment: can you help me with configuration of appdynamics with my application?
I am new to this so facing difficulty in this?

Comment: Docs are online at http://docs.appdyanmics.com and there is a quickstart wizard in the product. Support is also available to help you. You can drop me a message as well on twitter or just jkowall at kowall.net

Answer (score 1):

You basically need the AppDynamics Controller and a AppDynamics Machine-Agent which will be installed on the machine to monitor. In the Machine-Agent configuration you set the URI of the controller and the agent starts to report machine metrics to the controller. Then you can configure alarms, see metrics, create dashboards, etc. I can deliver you more information if you want, but as Jonah Kowall said, take a look at the documentation as well [AppDynamics Machine Agent Doc](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Standalone+Machine+Agent)